# How can this BitSet example print (false,true) or (true, false)?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, java-memory-model

I am trying to understand the JMM by following the [blog post by Aleksey Shipilëv](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/#_test_your_understanding_2)

[image]

The above example is breaking my mind.

> Explanation: There are 3 threads the first 2 threads (the *1st* and *2nd* column) run `set()` without any locking and the 3rd thread (3rd column) waits for the previous threads to terminate and then tries to read the values written by the previous threads.

If 2 threads run `bs.set(1)` and `bs.set(2)` respectively without any locking how can they give inconsistent results?

According to the internals the `BitSet` is implemented using `long[]` and bitshifts.

Bit shifting is a constant time operation, right? I simply cannot work out how this is even possible.

Comment: How does bit shifting being constant time affect the thread safety of BitSet?

Comment: `bs.set(1)` and `bs.set(2)` will both end up writing to the same `long` value inside the class. That means one could clobber the other's write if they happen at the same time.

Comment: Thread one: read the current value of the long (0). Thread two: read the current value of the long (0). Thread one: update the value of the long adding the 1-bit (1). Thread two: update the value of the long adding the 2-bit (2). The final value of the long is 2, but if both bits were set, it would be 3.

Comment: (Please refrain from adding "Any help?" and "thanks" in your posts).

Comment: (Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose bits are stored inside a long variable `v`.

- When just bit 1 is set, `v` would equal 2.
- When just bit 2 is set, `v` would equal 4.
- When both bits are set, `v` would equal 6 (i.e. `2|4`).

If you set them sequentially, you get something like this:

- `v` starts at 0.
- `bs.set(1)`

  - Read `v` (0)
  - Add `2` to indicate that bit 1 is on
  - Update `v` (2)
- `bs.set(2)`

  - Read `v` (2)
  - Add `4` to indicate that bit 2 is on
  - Update `v` (6)

Now `v` is 6, so both bits are on.

---

If you set them simultaneously, you can get something like this:

- `v` starts at 0
- Thread 1: `bs.set(1)`
- Thread 2: `bs.set(2)`
- Thread 1: Read `v` (0)
- Thread 2: Read `v` (0)
- Thread 1: Set `v` to 2 (i.e. `0|2`)
- Thread 2: Set `v` to 4 (i.e. `0|4`)

Now `v` is set to 4, so bit 2 is on and bit 1 is off.

Answer (score 0):

As the Author stated: **BitSet Javadocs say multi-threaded usages should be synchronized, so this is arguably an artificial example**

The JVM makes no guarantees of atomic operations for `Bitwise OR: ior, lor.`

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.3

The BitSet make not attempt to make atomic changes either.

See: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/BitSet.java

```
/**
 * Sets the bit at the specified index to {@code true}.
 *
 * @param  bitIndex a bit index
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if the specified index is negative
 * @since  1.0
 */
public void set(int bitIndex) {
    if (bitIndex < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("bitIndex < 0: " + bitIndex);

    int wordIndex = wordIndex(bitIndex);
    expandTo(wordIndex);

    words[wordIndex] |= (1L << bitIndex); // Restores invariants

    checkInvariants();
}
```

When the `lor` is carried can not be determined in a multiprocessor system.

To be more precise:

```
`lload`  words[wordIndex]
`lor`    (1L << bitIndex)
`lstore` words[wordIndex]
```

These 3 commands can switch at anytime between the 2 threads.